# iMessages not synced between Mavericks and Yosemite

Tags: macos, data-synchronization, messages

I have two Macs, one with Mavericks and one with Yosemite. Ever since I’ve upgraded to Yosemite, iMessages are no longer in sync between the two. I use the Mavericks one as my primary machine and when I go to the other one, the only messages I see are the one pre-upgrade. I tried logging out and logging back in on both, but to no avail. How can I fix this problem?

The email address used for the account is the same in both instances and I do not use an iOS device, so there is no phone number associated with said account.

Comment: It may have to do with which phone or email addresses are being used by each instance of iMessage and which one is the primary (send messages from) address.

Comment: @JaimeSantaCruz I updated my question with some more details. The email address is the same in each instance and there is no phone number involved.